# Will deleting a WhatsApp message in a conversation with my girlfriend makes her to loose trust on me?

Tags: relationships, long-distance

It is a short term + long-distance relationship, I am trying to build the trust.

When we were texting in WhatsApp I deleted a message with ta ypo (delete for everyone) and she asked me what did I delete, I just told her that 'it is a secret', just for fun. But, It seems she got annoyed by it and suddenly she went cold since yesterday.

Is this action make her to act in such a way or I am just overthinking?

Comment: It seems she did not appreciate the joke. Probably tell her it was a typo you deleted, and you were just teasing her

Comment: Hi Ganesh, this was closed as opinion-based since we can't know what she is thinking. You can check out our [help/on-topic] for more info on what questions we can answer here - for instance, if you'd like to know how to reach out and explain or apologize to her, you could [edit] your question to ask that instead.